# Can I switch from Firefox 32-bit to Firefox 64-bit without losing data?

Tags: firefox, 64-bit, passwords, bookmarks, history

I'm currently using Firefox 32-bit, but since the release of the version 43.0, Firefox is also [available in 64-bit for Windows](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/43.0/releasenotes/).

I would be pleased to use this Firefox build, but I don't want to lose my data, and especially not my bookmarks, my history, my passwords and the installed add-ons.

Will the install remove any of these? If that's the case, is there a way to circumvent this problem?

Comment: The Firefox program is stored separately from your profile, which contains your settings, history, bookmarks, passwords, add-ins, etc.  Generally, changes to the Firefox software, don't touch your profile (although add-ins that aren't compatible with a newer version will be disabled).  As a precaution, you can backup, or temporarily change the name of, the parent (firefox or mozilla) directory that holds your profile to protect it.  It's generally a good idea to back that up anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, it worked just fine, and you can't tell the difference once the 64-bit version launches.

Comment: Do the program files move from Program Files (x86) to Program Files? Any leftovers?

Comment: @user3169 The best way to find out would be to check.

Comment: Not that I can tell. It looks just like it overwrites the EXE, but everything else is just the same. I haven't seen anything to tell it's different except the dates on a few files.

Comment: Hmm...then I wonder what the benefit of switching is. Generally it is preferable not to change things needlessly.

Comment: The benefit would be the expanded RAM available to 64-bit applications. You hit upon the question which is why the 64-bit version was put off for so long as a start then stop project. Many thought it wasn't worth pursuing.

Comment: It has indeed worked perfectly! Can you add to your answer the informations about the profiles in [the comment made by fixer1234]? It will be more complete. @user3169, FYI, Firefox 64-bit erased the previous installation if possible, so it goes to `Program Files (x86)` if you haven't uninstalled Firefox 32-bit, or to `Program Files` otherwise. I've checked personally :).